# CIVICRM Create API for event participate

Tags: civievent, participants

I create an event. I need to create an API for Event Participate(Registration) page. I also retrieve all participates users data via API too. Please let me know .
I just go API v3 . And see there is Event in Entity fields. I choose it. I choose get .I see there is return form too.I need all participates information . what their address,nationality and some customs fields too. I see there is create function but I don't know how can I add fields.please let know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Md Maidul Islam,

Bit difficult to understand from your question what you want to achieve.

1 - Do you mean to add participant for an event? Then you can use Entity = Participant and Action = Create api

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Participant', 'create', [
  'event_id' => 3,
  'contact_id' => 51,
]);
```

2 - Do you mean to add participant for an event with all contact details in one call ? Then you can use Entity = Contact and Action = Create chain api

```
$params = [
    'display_name' => 'batman',
    'contact_type' => 'Individual',
    'api.address.create' => [
      'contact_id' => '$value.id',
      'location_type_id' => 6,
      'street_name' => 'Ambachtstraat',
      'street_number' => '23',
      'street_address' => 'Ambachtstraat 23',
      'postal_code' => '6971 BN',
      'country_id' => '1152',
      'city' => 'Brummen',
      'is_primary' => 1,
    ],
    'api.email.create' => [
      'contact_id' => '$value.id',
      'location_type_id' => 'Main',
      'email' => 'api@a-team.com',
      'is_primary' => 1,
    ],
    'api.phone.create' => [
      'contact_id' => '$value.id',
      'location_type_id' => 6,
      'phone' => '(123) 456-7890',
      'is_primary' => 1,
      'phone_type_id' => 1,
    ],
    'api.participant.create' => [
      'contact_id' => '$value.id',
      'event_id' => 2,
      'status_id' => 1,
      'role_id' => 1,
      'register_date' => '2007-07-21 00:00:00',
      'source' => 'Online Event Registration: API Testing',
      'custom_1' => 'custom string',
    ],
  ];
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', $params);
```

3 - Do you mean to get participant of an event with all contact details in one call ?

```
   $params = array(
    'contact_id' => 2,
    'event_id' => 3,
    'api.contact.get' => 1,
    'api.email.get' => ['contact_id' => '$value.contact_id'],
    'api.address.get' => ['contact_id' => '$value.contact_id'],
    'api.phone.get' => ['contact_id' => '$value.contact_id'],
  );
```

HTH

Pradeep

Note: The params build above are not tested, but its the syntax on how one can build params when using chain api.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I will try and let you know. Is there any tutorials blogs or youtube  regarding that. Please let me know.